# How to resolve the issue modal confirm dialog not working twitter bootstrap datatable sorter?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have added a column for delete option with confirm() to delete record in each row of datatable.Its working fine in first page of datatable, When i click the delete icon in second page of datatable its not working. Please help me how to resolve the issue.

Here i had tried the code.

```
<table class="table table-striped datatable" id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>Option </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

              <?php
              $query = mysql_query("SELECT id,state FROM state_list");
              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
              ?>
                <tr class="odd gradeX order-delete" id="ordrrow-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                    <td><?php echo $row['state']; ?></td>
                    <td class="center"><a href="" id="<?php echo "btn-".$row['id']; ?>" class="delete">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="datatable-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bootbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datatable').dataTable();    
    $('.order-delete').click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);
    e.preventDefault();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure? ", function(r) {
        if (r) {
            //sent request to delete order with given id
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'delete.php',
                data: {order_id: id},
                success: function(b) {
                    if (b) {
                        //delete row
                        orTable.fnDeleteRow($('tr#ordrrow-' + id)[0]);
                    } else {
                        //failed to delete, sent noty in
                        notify({
                            text: "Failed to delete, please try again later",
                            layout: "topCenter",
                            type: "alert",
                            timeout: 3
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});


} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your only binding the click action to the `.order-delete` elements you can see at the time js runs.

Try changing this line:

```
$('.order-delete').click(function(e) {
```

to

```
 $(document).on('click', '.order-delete', function(e) {
```

What this does is binds to every click on the page then filters them out by your class.

This is also Extremely useful for ajax and single page sites.